# Qual é o significado desta definição de valores?

Tags: javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript">
perfBar.init({
    budget: { 
        // the key is the metric id
        'loadTime': {
            max: 200
        },
        'redirectCount': {
            max: 1
        },
        'globalJS': {
            min: 2,
            max: 5
        }
    }
});
</script>
```

(O código acima referido é apenas um exemplo.)

Gostaria de saber, o que estou fazendo exatamente ao definir esses valores usando um arquivo externo. 
O que seria isso, um objeto?

Comment: "quando estou usando algum arquivo externo" Desculpe, não entendi, o que seria esse arquivo externo? Você está simplesmente dizendo que o script que define `perfBar` está num arquivo diferente do que o usa (e se for isso, é irrelevante, todo JS na página executa sob o mesmo contexto) ou é outra coisa?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Isso é um **literal de objeto** sendo passado como argumento para uma função inicializadora.

Um literal é uma forma de se definir/construir uma estrutura de dados no próprio código-fonte do programa, em vez de por meio de uma série de chamadas e/ou a definição explícita de um tipo/classe. Exemplo:

```
var obj = {
  budget: { 
    // the key is the metric id
    'loadTime': {
      max: 200
    },
    'redirectCount': {
      max: 1
    },
    'globalJS': {
      min: 2,
      max: 5
    }
  }
};
```

É equivalente a:

```
var obj = new Object();
obj.budget = new Object();
obj.budget.loadTime = new Object();
obj.budget.loadTime.max = 200;
...
```

Esse formato de literal é comumente referido como JSON, mas na realidade são conceitos diferentes (JSON é um formato de **texto**, inspirado nos objetos JavaScript, porém mais restrito no formato e mais geral na aplicação).

```
// É um texto, não um literal; e repare no uso obrigatório das aspas duplas
var meuJSON = '{ "budget": { "loadTime": { "max": 200 }, "redirectCount": { "max": 1 }, "globalJS": { "min": 2, "max": 5 } } }';

var obj = JSON.parse(meuJSON); // Cria o mesmo objeto definido acima
```

A passagem de um objeto complexo como argumento de uma função é comumente usada para:

- Passar parâmetros opcionais - se sua função opera bem de forma "padrão" mas há muitos detalhezinhos que o programador pode ou não querer ajustar, então em vez de uma lista imensa de parâmetros é preferível aceitar um objeto e ler dele esses parâmetros opcionais. Isso a torna mais conveniente de ser invocada;
- Operar sobre uma estrutura de dados genérica - nesse caso, seria o mesmo passar um literal ou um objeto contido numa variável. Só que se você não vai usar esse objeto depois fora do contexto da função, não é necessário criá-lo e usá-lo em duas etapas distintas, pode-se fazer tudo numa operação só (ajuda a "despoluir o *namespace*").

O que esse seu método `init` está fazendo, não sei, mas pelo jeito é um misto de um ou outro (i.e. vários desses argumentos me parecem necessários, mas nem todos, de modo que receber um objeto permite ao programador escolher o que passar pra função sem ter que ficar repetindo `null`, `null`, `null` para todos os parâmetros que não se aplicam).

Answer (score 2):

Você está usando uma notação chamada JSON, para passar os arqgumentos para um médoto chamado `init()` da sua `perfBar`.

### [Definição de JSON](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON)

> JSON (com a pronúncia ['dʒejzən]), um acrônimo para "JavaScript Object Notation", é um formato leve para intercâmbio de dados computacionais. JSON é um subconjunto da notação de objeto de JavaScript, mas seu uso não requer JavaScript exclusivamente.

Comment: "JSON é um subconjunto da notação de objeto de JavaScript..." e é essa notação de objeto de JavaScript que está sendo usada de fato, não JSON. Mesmo porque JSON não permite aspas simples (ou omissão das aspas), o que JS permite.

Answer (score 0):

O que acontece nesse caso é que você está fazendo uma chamada ao método init() e passando um objeto json como argumento.

Comment: Tem uma pequena diferença entre um "objeto json" e um "literal de objeto", JSON é um formato de **texto**, que independe da linguagem de programação.