# Qual a utilidade / razão da existência de new Object();?

Tags: javascript, característica-linguagem, construtor, literal

Enquanto estudava um pouco mais sobre objetos, me deparei com coisas como `new String` , `new Number`, etc.

Fiquei curioso, e fui aprender. Entendi o funcionamento, apesar de ter minhas dúvidas sobre a utilidade dos mesmos, haja visto que meu conhecimento ainda não é muito grande. Mas até aí, tudo bem.

Então me deparei com o `new Object()`. Fiquei confuso. Pensei que se ele existe, deve haver uma diferença ao invés de declarar com um simples `{}`, mas ao que parece, não há.

Se não há diferenças entre fazer um e fazer outro, qual a utilidade da sintaxe mais longa? Qual a razão pela qual esse construtor foi criado?

Comment: Eu já li essa pergunta, e não creio que seja uma duplicata. Sei a diferença entre Object.create e new Object, estou perguntando a diferença entre `x = {}` e `x = new Object();`. Aliás, a pergunta seria, se não há diferença entre os dois, por que existe o `new Object();`.

Comment: Nessa própria pergunta, a resposta aceita diz que usar `new Object()` era "coisa de dinossauros pedantes". Se é algo "inútil", por que existe?

Comment: Relacionado: [Qual é o significado desta definição de valores](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/68668/qual-é-o-significado-desta-definição-de-valores/68681#68681)

Comment: Relacionada (SOen): [What is the difference between `new Object()` and object literal notation?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4597926/1452488)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A pergunta deveria ser "por que não deveria ter `new Object()?`".

Ao contrário do que muita gente pensa (mesmo que diga que não pensa assim), a construção da linguagem segue uma lógica, tem uma gramática.

Isso é bom para o programador (de verdade) aprender mais facilmente e poder usar a intuição (com muito cuidado) para entender tudo como funciona nela, e pode ser mais fácil usar. É o mesmo de aprender uma língua normal (eu sei que muitos só decoram palavras e frases, mas muitos vão evoluindo o conhecimento de forma natural e progressiva, sempre entendendo o que está falando, o que faz com que ela entenda o todo, o conceito e não apenas as palavras, afinal se não for assim é uma forma de analfabetismo funcional), salvo regras de exceção necessárias por algum motivo as construções seguem uma lógica.

Também é bom para a construção do compilador que precisa tratar tudo de forma consistente e linear, ou seja, não precisa ficar inventando regras fora do normal sem necessidade.

Então se você pode usar o construtor para diversos objetos específicos para outros tipos, porque não deveria poder usar para o objeto genérico? Pra que fazer a exceção disso? Toda exceção precisa ser justificada. Criaram o construtor, não o construtor de `Object`.

Lembrando que pode (ou não) passar um parâmetro para esta função construtora. Em outros tipos é bastante comum que tenha parâmetros e faz muito mais sentido. Aliás, o literal dos outros tipos é justamente `new <Tipo>([param])`. Novamente, pra que esconder o construtor de um tipo específico? Então nem sempre são idênticos.

Não deveria, mas alguém poderia sobrepor o `Object` padrão em alguma situação anormal. E tem [diferença pra uso normal](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36629393/221800). Se não tivesse nada diferente alguém poderia argumentar para não usar algo que é claramente pior (e aparentemente [é pior até em performance, pelo menos em alguma implementação e situação específica](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21436082/221800)), mas seria ideologia.

Vendo [uma resposta aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/68681/101) que diz que ambos são equivalentes, significa ser semanticamente equivalente, não que dê o mesmo resultado (isso até dá) e da mesma forma.

É uma questão de simetria. A construção de linguagens, especialmente de programação, precisam ser pragmáticas, você ganhou ele "de graça" e para não ter haverá um custo, então melhor deixar ali. Vai que alguém acha um motivo pra usar, ou arrumem uma otimização ou função que não muda a semântica do seu uso padrão e legado porém fornecendo alguma vantagem?

Existe por pragmatismo. Retirá-lo seria ideologia.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/JavaScript/Conceptual.md).